# Google Apps Script execution error Network Error 0x80004004 in IE

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a google apps script to display some charts and data from various spreadsheets, thinking I could then share that link and people could view the data. Works like a charm in chrome. When viewed in IE, however...

The page itself shows "Invalid Json" and I get a Network Error 0x80004004 in the console. No idea how to proceed with it.

Comment: It's possible that this could turn out to be a bug.  But we need to know exactly what the process is, the timing of when the error occurs, and if it is from a specific line of code.  Does the error occur when the spreadsheet is opened?  When the user does something specific?  When code is run?  What triggers the error?  JSON is a format for storing data in an object.  It must have something to do with data that you are retrieving or using.  Can you duplicate the error with some simple code that you can post?

Comment: The error occurs when the script is executed in not-chrome. Here is the link for the script: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxR4Wp37pbDT8eXOhzpJM1z_T9T_e8vwvaZpPvec3N-b_KCqxXa/exec

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Element that is displaying the error:

[image: invalid JSON]

is the Fourth table element in the HTML

[image: Fourth Table]

That msg is being shown from an HTML Span Tag.

[image: Span Tag]

I opened the Chrome **Tools**, **Developer Tools** window, and clicked on the **Elements** tab to show the HTML that was served.

That gives me a better idea of what is happening, but the client side Javascript code is sanitized with Caja, and I can't read it.  There are `<script>` tags in the HTML, so there must be JavaScript code running in the browser, but again, it sanitized with Caja, so I can't figure it out.

[image]

Plus if there is server side .gs code running, I can't see that with the Developer tools.  That HTML Span tag is probably being hidden or displayed in JavaScript code from a HTML Script tag.  But without seeing the original HTML file there is no way anyone can figure out what is happening.

Oh, and if that is the error you are talking about, I'm getting it in Chrome.  But I don't have the same permissions that you do.  So, I'm wondering if it's something to do with a permission setting.